# Is there an expression for the coefficients of the falling factorial $x^{\underline n} \equiv x (x-1) \dots (x-n+1)$?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, binomial-theorem, stirling-numbers

Consider the falling factorial

$$
x^{\underline n} = x (x-1) \dots (x-n+1)
$$

This is clearly a polynomial of degree $n$. Is there an expressions for the coefficients of that polynomial? I tried taking derivatives and substituting $x=0$ to get the coefficients but the expressions I am getting are very complicated.

Comment: "The coefficients that appear in the expansions are Stirling numbers of the first kind" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: Stirling numbers of the first kind are in a sense the analog of binomial coefficients for falling powers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes indeed,
Notice that you can either get an $x$ or a number when you unfold it, hence the coefficient of $x^k$ in that expression is
$$(-1)^{n-k}\sum _{\substack{S\subseteq [n-1]\\|S|=n-k}}\prod _{s\in S}s,$$
this is not very simple to compute, but is a closed formula. For example, when $k=1$ you get $(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!.$ This numbers have a name, they are called Stirling numbers of the first kind. They satisfy a recurrence that can be explicit  from the definition of the falling factorial.