# Why are Stirling numbers of the first kind related to the number of permutations with $k$ cycles?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions, stirling-numbers, permutation-cycles

As discussed *e.g.* in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3853769/173147), as well as [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), we have
$$(x)_n \equiv x(x-1)\cdots (x-(n-1)) = \sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k) x^k,$$
where $s(n,k)$ are the so-called *Stirling numbers of the first kind*. These are also written as
$$s(n,k) = (-1)^{n-k} \left[\begin{matrix}n\\k \end{matrix}\right],$$
where $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ are the *unsigned* Stirling numbers of the first kind, which are also the coefficients of the polynomial expansion of $x^{\overline n}\equiv x(x+1)\cdots (x+(n-1))$.

It is not hard to see that these are tightly related to sums of powers of integers:
$$x^{\bar n}
= x^n + x^{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(k-1)\right)
+ x^{n-2}\left(\sum_{i<j=1}^{n}(i-1)(j-1)\right)+\cdots + x\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)\right).$$

The unsigned Stirling numbers $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}n\\k \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ are also equal to the number of permutations of $n$ elements which are composed of exactly $k$ disjoint cycles. *E.g.* $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}3\\2 \end{smallmatrix}\right]=3$ because the permutations in $S_3$ with two cycles are (in cycle notation), $(12)$, $(13)$, and $(23)$.

Is there a good way to see the connection between these two definitions? More specifically, why are the coefficients of $x^{\overline n}$ connected to the number of this particular type of permutations? Equivalently, why does counting these classes of permutations result in expressions involving these sums of products of integers?

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice proof, which is similar to the proof that
$$
(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kx^k
$$
by counting the number of ways to expand $(x+1)^n$ with the distributive property.

It is helpful to write $x^{\overline n}$ as
$$
(x+1+\dots+1)\cdots (x+1+1)(x+1)x
$$
When you expand this out with the distributive property, there are $n!$ terms, as you have $n$ choices for the term from $(x+1+\dots+1)$, then $n-1$ choices from the second factor, and so on down to $1$ choice from the $x$ factor. When choosing from the $k^{th}$ factor, there are $n-k+1$ choices, and exactly one choice will increase the resulting power of $x$.

On the other hand, consider the following method of choosing a permutation, $\pi$. You first choose $\pi(1)$, from one of $n$ options. Then, you choose $\pi(\pi(1))$, then $\pi(\pi(\pi(1)))$, and so on until you complete a cycle. Then, you choose $\pi(s)$, where $s$ is the smallest unassigned element, etc. During the $k^{th}$ stage of this process, you have $n-k+1$ options. Exactly one of these leads to the creation of a cycle.

After some thought, these processes are exactly the same, so that the number of ways to choose a permutation with $k$ cycles is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $x^{\overline n}$.

Comment: could you go into a little bit more detail? When counting the number of terms with a given power $x^k$, you also need to take into account the ways in which you can choose the rows, no? In your counting you seem to be only taking into account the terms $x^k$ resulting from taking $1$s in the first $n-k$ rows.

Answer (score 3):

$\require{cancel}$

This answer contains exactly the same information as that of Mike's. It is just more elaborate.

Write the product $x^{\overline{n}}$

$$x^{\overline{n}}=\left(x+\underset{n-1\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1+\dots+1}}\right)\cdots\left(1+x\right)x.$$

Imagine the process of expanding this product from the left. We record which summand (from the left) we choose on the $k$th term $\left(x+\underset{n-k\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1+\dots+1}}\right)$. Say that you chose the $i_k$th summand from the $k$th term. We define a sequence $j_1,\dots,j_n$ by

$$j_{k+1}=i_{k+1}\text{th smallest element in }\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{j_1,\dots,j_{k}\}.$$

The sequence $j_1\dots j_{n}$ is a reordering of $1,\dots ,n$. Now for each $k$ such that $i_k=1,$ put a slash "/" between $j_{k}$ and $j_{k+1}.$ This means that if you chose $i$ $x$'s, then you have $i$ slashes. The resulting sequence looks like

$$j_1\dots j_{k_{1}}/j_{k_1+1}\dots j_{k_2}/\dots/j_{k_{i}+1}\dots j_{n},$$

and we can regard this sequence as a permutation which is the product of $i$ cycles. Since every such permutation arises uniquely in this way, the coefficient of $x^i$ in $x^{\overline{n}}$ counts the number of permutations which is the product of precisely $i$ cycles.

---

As an example, consider the case $n=4$ and $i_1=3$, $i_2=1$, $i_3=2$, and $i_4=1$. In this case
$$
\begin{align}
j_1&= 3\text{rd smallest element in} \{1,2,3,4\}=3,\\
j_2&= 1\text{st smallest element in} \{1,2,\cancel{3},4\}=1,\\
j_3&= 2\text{nd smallest element in } \{\cancel{1},2,\cancel{3},4\}=4,\\
j_4&= 1\text{st smallest element in} \{\cancel{1},2, \cancel{3},\cancel{4}\}=2,\\
\end{align}
$$
so the resulting permutation will be $(31)(42)$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the notation. In your definition of $j_k$, don't you just get $j_k=k$, making it a trivial reordering? Assuming I understand the notation: that you remove from the set $\{1,...,n\}$ the set $\{j_1,...,j_k\}$ and then take the smallest remaining value. But then $j_1=\min(\{1,...,n\})=1$, $j_2=\min(\{2,...,n\})=2$, etc

Comment: also, $i_k=1$ means you pick the $x$ summand in the $k$-th term? So that for example we can have $i_1\in\{1,...,n\}$, $i_2\in\{1,...,n-1\}$, and more generally $i_k\in\{1,...,n-k+1\}$? Also, the last equation should represent a term in the expansion of $x^{\bar n}$, right? So the number of slashes corresponds to the power of $x$ in the resulting expression. I think I'm kind of getting the idea here, but a simple example would make it much easier to digest the notation

Comment: @glS You are totally right about the definition of $j_k$. I edited it to a correct definition. Thank you for pointing it out!

You're right in assuming that $i_k\in \{1,\dots,n-k+1\}$. I added an example at the end of the answer to illustrate how the process works. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. I'm still not too comfortable with this notation, but reading this and then rereading Mike's answer I finally understood the underlying idea I think. Maybe I'll try to also write my own answer using a notation I personally find more natural

Comment: @glS I agree that my notations are a bit clumsy :) Glad to know that it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, probably, is by recursion. Notice that $x^{\overline{n+1}}=(x+n)x^{\overline{n}}$ just by distributing the product, this creates the recursion $${n+1 \brack k}={n \brack k-1}+n\cdot {n \brack k}.$$ The first terms you can think about it by placing $n+1$ as a fix point(so you create a new cycle) and the other term can be seen as placing $n+1$ as the pre-image of some element $x$ and the old pre-image as the preimage of $n+1.$ These choice of $x$ can be done in $n$ ways.

Comment: Now, if you want to really grasp combinatorially this concept, I suggest you compute an expression for the numbers and think about cycle structure of permutations. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630227/coefficients-of-a-falling-factorial

Answer (score 0):

I will present a way to count the number of permutations in $S_n$ composed of exactly $k\le n$ cycles, that will naturally give expressions of the form $\sum_{i_1\cdots i_k=1}^{n} (i_1-1)\cdots(i_k-1)$, which as mentioned in the question equals ${n\brack k}$.

### Specific example: ${4\brack2}$

To this end, I'll start from a specific example, and only afterward discuss the general approach. Consider then the permutations in $S_4$ composed of two cycles. There are two [cycle types](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_type_of_a_permutation) compatible with having two cycles: $(22)$ and $(31)$. We will list the possible permutations $\pi\in S_4$ as follows:

1. Start asking where $1$ is sent by $\pi$, that is, what is $\pi(1)$. If $\pi(1)=1$, then we are dealing with a (31) cycle. We then take the lowest "unused" integer (so in this case $2$) and ask what is $\pi(2)$. Now, because we want two cycles overall, $2$ must belong to a 3-cycle, meaning $2\neq\pi(2)\neq\pi^2(2)$ and $\pi^3(2)=2$. Counting the corresponding number of permutations is easy: $1$ and $2$ are fixed, and the remaining number of 3-cycles are $2\times1=2$. In other words, we just counted the number of permutations of the form
   $$(s)(s\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet}).$$
   We'll use this notation again in the following: each $s$ means "fill this place with the smallest available integer", and each $\bullet$ means "any available integer can be put here". So to be more explicit, the two $S_4$ permutations compatible with $(s)(s\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet})$ are
   $(1)(234)$ and $(1)(243)$.
2. If $\pi(1)\neq1$ but $\pi^2(1)=1$, then we have a $(22)$ cycle structure. We will use the same approach as above to count these: we consider permutations of the form
   $$(s\,{\bullet})(s\,{\bullet}),$$
   which includes $3\times1$ permutations, and more specifically, the permutations $(12)(34), (13)(24)$, and $(14)(23)$.
3. The last remaining possibility is that $1$ fits in a 3-cycle. This means cycles of the form
   $$(s\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet})(s).$$
   There are $3\times2$ of these, which are explicitly
   $$(123)(4),(124)(3),(132)(4),(134)(2),(142)(3),(143)(2).$$
   Let me stress that, while these permutations have the same cycle structure as in the point 1 above, there is no overlap between the permutations in $(s\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet})(s)$ and those in $(s)(s\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet})$, meaning we can simply sum the individual counts to get the total number of permutations of cycle type $(31)$.

So, overall, we found that the number of $S_4$ permutations with two cycles equals $2\cdot1+3\cdot1+3\cdot2$, which is exactly the expression we were looking for.

### General case

More generally, our approach to count $S_n$ permutations with $k$ cycles is to count such permutations by writing all possible expressions with $s$ and $\bullet$ like above containing $k$ cycles.
This, however, leaves the problem of having to "select" the appropriate cycle structure when writing down the expressions. Fortunately, this is not really a problem: we can observe that the parentheses in the above expressions are completely redundant: we could have equivalently wrote $ss{\bullet}{\bullet}$ and $s{\bullet}s{\bullet}$ with no ambiguity as what is the corresponding cycle structure. The strings are understood as prescribing that a new cycle is started every time we get an "$s$" symbol.

We can thus conclude that the possible $S_n$ permutations with $k$ cycles are all and only those coming from strings of length $n$ containing "$s$" and "$\bullet$", with exactly $k$ copies of "$s$", with the additional rule that the first symbol is always an "$s$".

As an additional example, that means to count ${5\brack 2}$ we consider strings of the form
$$sss\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet},
\qquad ss\,{\bullet}\,s\,{\bullet},
\qquad ss\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet}\,s,
\qquad s\,{\bullet}\,ss\,{\bullet},
\qquad s\,{\bullet}\,s\,{\bullet}\,s,
\qquad s\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet}\,ss.
$$
It is easy to count the number of permutations in each of this strings: we just multiply the positions corresponding to each of the $\bullet$ in the string, counting positions from $1$ from the right. So for the example above, we have the correspondence:
$$sss\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet} \to 2\times1,
\qquad ss\,{\bullet}\,s\,{\bullet} \to 3\times1,
\qquad ss\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet}\,s \to 3\times2, \\
s\,{\bullet}\,ss\,{\bullet} \to 4\times1,
\qquad s\,{\bullet}\,s\,{\bullet}\,s \to 4\times2,
\qquad s\,{\bullet}\,{\bullet}\,ss \to 4\times3.
$$
As an additional consistency check, consider the permutations in $ss\,{\bullet}\,s\,{\bullet}$, which are $(1)(23)(45),(1)(24)(35),(1)(25)(34)$.

Summing all of these we get the expressions we wanted: ${5\brack2}=\sum_{i<j=1}^5 (i-1)(j-1)$.