# Expanding root polynomial form to general form

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, numerical-methods

Let's suppose we have a set of *n* data points:
$$(x_0,y_0), (x_1,y_1),...,(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})$$

then Newton polynomial is given by:

$$P(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{k}(x-x_i)$$

Suppose we already know every lambda. How to expand the Newton's form to the general form of:

$$P(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k$$

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Check for Vieta relations.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630227/coefficients-of-a-falling-factorial this is when $x_i=i$

Comment: Check the section Main Idea here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial

Comment: Do you know how to do it for $n=2$? For $n=3$?

Comment: rewrite the math of Wikipedia and you will understand it... Their a is your $\lambda$

Comment: Is my answer enough or should I continue elaborating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through coefficient identification for the coefficients of $x^0, x^1, ... x^n$ in both written forms:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{k}(x-x_i) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k$$

means

$\lambda_0(x-x_0) +\lambda_1 (x-x_0)(x-x_1)+\lambda_2 (x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+...+\lambda_n (x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k$

The coefficient comparaison in the equation above leads to solving the following: I'll continue ...

$  
\begin{pmatrix}1 &.&  .  &.& 0\\
1 &(x_1-x_0)&.&.&0\\
1&  (x_2-x_0)&   (x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)&.&0\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
1&  (x_k-x_0)&   .&.&\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x_k-x_i)\\
\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_0\\
\lambda_1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
\lambda_k\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
a_k\\
\end{pmatrix}$

This can be solved iteratively.

Comment: I've tried solving this based on your answer and the "Main Idea" on wikipedia. The problem is, after calculating each $$a_i$$, it comes out that $$a_i = y_i$$, which is not the case obviously.

Comment: Where does $y_i$ come from? How did you introduce it in your verification?  There is no $y_i$ in $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\lambda_k\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{k}(x-x_i) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k$ That's why I am wondering where it came from...

Comment: Did you try to apply coefficient identification to find $a_k$ for all $0 \le k \le n$ ?

Comment: No, in fact I did not